# Japanese quote marks!

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to construct a short post for my social media, **in Japanese**, because many of our customers are Japanese.

I don't want to make a mess.

I am using a quote from a Japanese review left on Tripadvisor from a customer. I want to know if this is the correct way to express it is a quote from Tripadvisor, because I don't understand how to use the quote marks in Japanese correctly!

This is the original text:

> 本格的アルゼンチン料理で、美味しい肉を堪能させて頂きました。tripadvisorのレビュー

So do I just use these marks to make it into a quote? And then state the origin of the quote? 「」

e.g

> 「本格的アルゼンチン料理で、美味しい肉を堪能させて頂きました。」tripadvisorのレビュー

Because I read on another site that I may need to add some other characters...

[image]

Comment: What's that you intend to write in English?

Comment: As far as the quotation mark usage goes, the way you have it written is fine.

Comment: Hi Broccoli forest, thanks for replying, I want to write in Japanese, but Ii am taking a section of the whole review and placing it in a different format (as a quote) so I just want to make sure that I have structured it correctly with the quote marks and the Tripadvisor origin statement.

Comment: Thanks By137, so no extra characters necessary to express its a quote?

Comment: Good to see how the phrasing is used in context (your provided image). If I may suggest [an improvement to the typesetting](https://i.imgur.com/71AwIjN.png)

Comment: Gratefully accepted Setris! Thanks so much for your help and effort to rework it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`「` and `」` are the most basic Japanese quotation marks, so what you are doing is basically correct. In addition, you can just use the "English-style" quotation marks, too:

> “本格的アルゼンチン料理で、美味しい肉を堪能させて頂きました。” — Tripadviserのレビュー

The difference is not large, but IMHO this style looks even slightly better in your case. Japanese people use [various types of quotation marks](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2017/05/quotation-marks-japanese.html), and they are used according to the situation (or personal taste, to some extent). In this case, the article itself is about an Argentine restaurant, so Western-origin punctuation is welcome.

Western people somehow love to place quotes everywhere (e.g., at the end of a movie trailer, at the beginning of each chapter of a novel, [at the start of a UNIX session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)), ...), but this habit itself already looks more or less "foreign" to the eyes of Japanese people, and Western-style quotation marks have been popular in such cases. For example, [this article](https://copypet.jp/889/) is about how to design a good-looking `<blockquote>` with CSS, and you can see how the "double-comma" icon is widely recognized as an indicator of quote.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a really useful explanation, thank you Naruto. Ive added the final post so you can see how it looks. Thanks again for everyones help!

Comment: @KatandPancho Your image looks very good :)